# Calculating Field Chosen by arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) gives ERROR 000539?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, parameters, error-000539

I add a parameter CampoConfere = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) which get a field from Tabela_Base to calculate in the next steps from the code. The Scripts works well until the Calculate Field Step when the prompt says that "CampoConfere" is not valid. Why Python do not calculate this parameter?

```
import arcpy

Tabela_Base = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
CampoConfere = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
arcpy.AddMessage('Tabela de Entrada: '+Tabela_Base)
arcpy.AddMessage('Campo: '+CampoConfere)
fields = arcpy.ListFields(Tabela_Base)
ValidaCampo = sum(field.name == CampoConfere and field.type == "Single" for field in fields)

if not ValidaCampo:

    Nome_Campo = "CHAVEIBGE2" 
    Tipo_Campo = "FLOAT" 
    Campo_Calculo = "CHAVEIBGE2"
    Saida1 = Tabela_Base

arcpy.AddField_management(Tabela_Base, Nome_Campo, Tipo_Campo, "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Saida1, Campo_Calculo, "!CampoConfere!", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

Them I get the message error:

> Executing: Script F:\AgroDB.gdb\IBGE\Brasil_Municipios COD_IBGE
>   Start Time: Fri Jun 23 08:46:05 2017
>   Running script Script...
>   Tabela de Entrada: F:\AgroDB.gdb\IBGE\Brasil_Municipios
>   Tabela de Entrada: COD_IBGE
>   Failed script Script...
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "F:\AgroDB.gdb\Modelo1.py", line 18, in 
>      arcpy.CalculateField_management(Saida1, Campo_Calculo, "!CampoConfere!", >"PYTHON_9.3", "")
>    File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", >line 3453, in CalculateField
>      raise e
>   ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: Invalid field CampoConfere
>   Failed to execute (CalculateField).
>
> Failed to execute (Script).
>   Failed at Fri Jun 23 08:46:06 2017 (Elapsed Time: 0,74 seconds)

Comment: That variable is not in scope for field calculator. After you've chosen a value it is essentially a constant, try specifying like "!{}!".format(CampoConfere) to substitute the *value* of the variable rather than the variable name.

Comment: I see that you have output `arcpy.AddMessage('Tabela de Entrada: '+Tabela_Base)` but I think it would also be useful to output a value coming from your tool dialog for `CampoConfere`, and then to show us what you get in the Results window as text.

Comment: @PolyGeo when I put another arcpy.AddMessage line, this is the output: "Executing: Script F:\AgroDB.gdb\IBGE\Brasil_Municipios COD_IBGE
Start Time: Fri Jun 23 08:16:12 2017
Running script Script...
Tabela de Entrada: F:\AgroDB.gdb\IBGE\Brasil_Municipios
Tabela de Entrada: COD_IBGE"
Failed script Script... the field name is right "COD_IBGE" but the python do not calculate the fields for the new column.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson the "{}" didnt working and i didn`t understand where I use your tip

Comment: Always put those output messages into your question body, and also update the code there do that we can see precisely what you ran and saw.

Comment: @PolyGeo updated.

Comment: Has the script been saved after making that change?  It seems odd not to see the second message if it has.

Comment: See now! It`s saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [Python String Formatting](https://pyformat.info/) to insert your variable into a string.

For example, if your field name is `SampleField`, you could use string formatting in this line

```
arcpy.AddMessage('Campo: {0}'.format(CampoConfere))
```

to produce an output like

```
Campo: SampleField
```

You can use `.format()` to insert variables into any string, so you can also use it in your `arcpy.CalculateField_management()`

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Saida1, Campo_Calculo, "!{0}!".format(CampoConfere), "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

Which, using your variables and my example field name above, would insert variables to make the actual command like:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("SampleFC", "CHAVEIBGE2", "!SampleField!", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

Additionally, if this line `ValidaCampo = sum(field.name == CampoConfere and field.type == "Single" for field in fields)` ever returns `True` then you will get errors as your last two lines are not indented into the `if not ValidaCampo:` block, yet they use variables only assigned within that `if` block.